# Find with date in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model (vehicleData) in Mongo that has some data stored, with this data:

model:

```
const VehicleDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  carStatus: String
}, { timestamps: true })
```

sample data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c177d2b6f3b4565ccb0aaf2"),
    "status" : "DRIVING",
    "createdAt" : "2018-12-17T08:47:57.788Z",
    "updatedAt" : "2018-12-17T08:47:57.788Z",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I'm trying to query by createdAt greater than a date, in a Node application.
I have tried this:

```
let start = moment('2018-01-01')
const query = { createdAt: { $gte: start.toISOString() } }
console.log(query) //outputs { createdAt: { '$gte': '2018-01-01T02:00:00.000Z' } }
const result = await VehicleData.find(query)
```

This results nothing in my node application, but if iI try to use this query in mongo console (or with a client such as RoboT or Compass) it responds the entry with the createAt greater than the date.
Anyone knows what I'm missing?

With the debug from mongoose on, I can see that what is being queried is

```
vehicledatas.find({ createdAt: { '$gte': new Date("Mon, 01 Jan 2018 02:00:00 GMT") } }, { projection: {} })
```

Comment: try `new Date('2018-01-01').toISOString()` also which mongoose version are you using ?

Comment: @AnouarKacem from my package.json: "mongoose": "^5.0.18" I have tried with your suggestion, same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the date in the database is of `Date` and you are passing it as `String` here with `.toISOString()`

So instead try to convert it to date object using [**`.toDate()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) function in moment

```
VehicleData.find({ createdAt: { $gte: moment('2018-01-01').toDate() } })
```

And also [**`timestamps`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) options in mongoose always creates the field `createdAt` and  the `updatedAt` of type [**`Date`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-date-js)

Comment: I fount the problem: the createdAt and the updatedAt are being stored as string and not as ISODate. I have updated the value and turned them into ISODate and now the query works. I will have to find out why they are being stored as strings rather than date.

Comment: Then its schema issue. You are declared it as date here using `timestamps` option and finding it with using `String` type.

Comment: Damn, I know what is happening. This is not a problem with the schema. I have copied these data from from another database, via ctrl+c  and ctrl+v, and then when I saved it via the interface from RoboT client, it pasted as plain text. My fault :-(